# TypeError: backend.setRooms(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal

I have a function that is called `setRooms(input)`:

```
 setRooms:function(input){
            $.post( "files/ajax.php?q", { i: input})
                .done(function( result ) {
                    return result;
                });
        },
```

I load the file, where the function is in with requirejs: `backend = require('backend')`.

When I now call the function:

```
saveAllRooms = function(){
        backend.setAllRooms(ko.utils.stringifyJson(allRooms)).then(function (results) {
            _getAllRooms();
        });
    }
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: backend.setRooms(...) is undefined
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To debug: Print first what you get from the form. Also check your function if its inside the document.ready(). Undefined means there's no method exist in the JS or the method is unreachable.